# Erlang connection reset

Tags: linux, rabbitmq, erlang

I have an api application that is running in a docker container, and since moving to AWS, the api stops daily with the error: Erlang closed the connection. I've monitored the server during that time and no IOPS seem to be causing this issue. Beyond that though, when the api fails, it won't restart on it's own on one of our clusters. I'm not sure where to find the logs to get more context and could use any input that may be helpful. Also, more context here, is that this api worked fairly well before in our data-center/physical server space, but now in AWS, it fails daily. Any thoughts or suggestions as to why this may be failing to restart?

I've looked at the syslogs and the application server logs and don't see any kind of failures. Maybe I'm not looking in the proper place. At this point, someone from one of our teams has to manually restart the api with an init.d command. I don't want to create a cron job to "fix" this because that's a band-aid and not a true fix.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't enough information on the structure of your app or its connections, so no one can give a "true fix".
The problem may be as small as configuring your nodes differently, changing some of the server's local configurations, or you may need some "keep alive" handler towards AWS.

Maybe try adding a manual periodic dump to see if its an accumulating problem, but I believe if Erlang closed the connection there's a problem between your API and AWS, and your API can't understand where it is located.